# How do I run Windows 10 System Recovery with only 1.5 GB of free space?

Tags: windows-10, system-recovery

Recently I've been trying to fix my old laptop, to do this I burned Windows 10 to a DVD, but it turns out I need at least 7-8 GB of free space to reinstall it. I already tried formatting the C drive (did nothing) and deleting program files through a backdoor which gave me access to run cmd as an administrator.

Currently the `dir` command tells me I have about 10 GB of free space, but both the Windows 10 installation disc and explorer are telling me I only have 1.5 GB of free space.

How should I fix this?

Comment: So you deleted all partitions on the drive and still couldn’t install Windows?

Comment: uhm, I just deleted all the files I could safely delete

Comment: You indicated you formatted the system  disk, but did you delete the other partitions on the disk?

Comment: @Ramhound then that means I didn't do that, I only deleted files I could safely delete.